# JPA Query to fetch data from different tables on base of foreign key

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 tables, I want to fetch data from these tables where their foreign key is same. I have written a sql query first by using union:

```
SELECT jw.widget_name,jw.user_id FROM dashboard.jira_widget as jw WHERE jw.user_id = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT uw.widget_name,uw.user_id FROM dashboard.unit_test_widget as uw WHERE uw.user_id = '1'
```

But Jpa doesn't support UNION at all.

Is there any other way to write this query in jpa?

Comment: Can you help me out here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121226/datasnapshot-not-exist

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to try this query :

```
EntityManager em;
Query query = em.createQuery('SELECT jw, uw FROM JiraWidget as jw, UnitTestWidget as uw WHERE jw.userId = uw.userId AND jw.userId=:user');
query.setParameter('user', user);
```

Since multiple Select expression are used, the result is of type Object[]:

```
List<Object[]> results query.getResultList();

for (Object[] myUnion: results) {
    JiraWidget jw = (JiraWidget) myUnion[0];
    UnitTestWidget uw = (UnitTestWidget) myUnion[1];
    //etc...
}
```